# Теги header, footer

Tags: html, css

Стоит ли пользоваться тегами <header> и <footer>? Все ли браузеры поддеривают эти теги или лучше пользоваться <div id="header"> , <div id="footer"> ? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста. Как вы обычно верстаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете смело использовать **header, footer, aside, nav и т.д.**
Для того, чтобы данные теги корректно отображались во всех браузерах, в частности это касается IE < 9, необходимо:

1. в файле CSS задать им **display: block;**
2. и во вторых использовать HTML5shiv. Подключить его можно следующим образом

   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

Удачи

Answer (score 0):

Вот классная шаблон, пользуюсь давно. http://html5boilerplate.com/ Очень доволен, теги html5 конечно нужно использовать, семантика кода.  Нужно идти в ногу со временем!:)